# I want to make it so that once the "selectAll" function is triggered, all the checkboxes get selected

Tags: onclick, sapui5

```
        <ScrollContainer>
                <l:Grid class="sServicepage" defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12" content="{oListOrderMod>/}">
                    <l:content>
                        <l:Grid class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" defaultSpan="L2 M6 S12" vSpacing="0">
                            <VBox>
                                <layoutData>
                                    <l:GridData span="L1 M12"/>
                                </layoutData>
                                <CheckBox class="checkBox" id="chkId2" />
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <layoutData>
                                    <l:GridData span="L2"/>
                                </layoutData>
                                <l:Grid class="mRight mTop" defaultSpan="L3 M7 S7" vSpacing="0">
                                    <Label color="blue" class="title" text="Crew Name:">
                                        <layoutData>
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L9 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Text class="red" text="{oListOrderMod>crew_name}"></Text>
                                    <Label class="title" text="Storage Loc.:">
                                        <layoutData>
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L9 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label text="{oListOrderMod>location}"></Label>
                                </l:Grid>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <layoutData>
                                    <l:GridData span="L3"/>
                                </layoutData>
                                <l:Grid class="mRight mTop" defaultSpan="L7 M7 S7" vSpacing="0">
                                    <Label class="title" text="Job #:">
                                        <layoutData>
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label design="{oListOrderMod>ptype_class}" text="{oListOrderMod>jobno}"></Label>
    
                                </l:Grid>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox >
                                <layoutData>
                                    <l:GridData span="L3"/>
                                </layoutData>
                                <l:Grid class="mRight mTop" defaultSpan="L6 M7 S7" vSpacing="0">
                                    <Label class="title fRight2" text="Structure ID:">
                                        <layoutData class="tRight">
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L6 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Text text="{oListOrderMod>str_id}"></Text>
                                    <Label class="title fRight2" text="Work Type:">
                                        <layoutData class="tRight">
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L6 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Text text="{oListOrderMod>work_type}"></Text>
                                </l:Grid>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox >
                                <l:Grid class="mRight mTop" defaultSpan="L4 M7 S7" vSpacing="0">
                                    <Label class="title fRight2" text="Line #:">
                                        <layoutData class="tRight">
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L8 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Text text="{oListOrderMod>lineno}"></Text>
                                    <Label class="title fRight2" text="Asset Type:">
                                        <layoutData class="tRight">
                                            <l:GridData linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" span="L8 M5 S5"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Text text="{oListOrderMod>asset_type}"></Text>
                                </l:Grid>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox >
                                <layoutData>
                                    <l:GridData span="L1 M12"/>
                                </layoutData>
                                <Button class="cust-icon icon2" icon="sap-icon://fob-watch"></Button>
                            </VBox>
                        </l:Grid>
                    </l:content>
                </l:Grid>
            </ScrollContainer>
```

JS:

```
    selectAll: function() {
        var that = this;
        that.byId("chkId2").setSelected(true);      
    },
```

I want to make so that once the "selectAll" function is triggered, all the checkboxes would get selected. Right now, only the ones that come after it is triggered get selected. How do I make it so that even the ones that came before the button for "selectAll" got clicked get selected.
[enter image description here][How I make it so that all the checkboxes get checked. Not just the ones that came after the "selectAll" function is triggered?]

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e5Hm.png)

Comment: Why don't you just use a table?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <CheckBox class="checkBox" checked="{oListOrderMod>checked}" />
```

```
 selectAll: function() {
        this.getView().getModel("oListOrderMod").setProperty("/checked",true);
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.